# How to reuse values from multiple columns in the select statement of mysql

Tags: mysql, join, denormalized

I have two tables. Table_1 has three foreign keys that are coming from the table_2. I need to select all rows from table_2 where ids are equal to the values of val_1, val_2 and val_3 of a specific row from table_1. For example:

```
SELECT val_1, val_2, val_3 from table_1 WHERE id = 1;
```

And then using the result of the first query run

```
SELECT name FROM table_2 WHERE id IN (101, 102, 103);
```

Is there a way to do it in one query?

table_1

| id | name | val_1 | val_2 | val_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | item1 | 101 | 102 | 103 |
| 2 | item2 | 104 | 105 | 106 |

table_2

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | sub_item1 |
| 102 | sub_item2 |
| 103 | sub_item3 |
| 104 | sub_item4 |
| 105 | sub_item5 |
| 106 | sub_item6 |

Comment: `JOIN`, it's called.

Comment: what do you want your results to look like?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to concatenate `val_1`, `val_2` and `val_3` in a subquery and use `FIND_IN_SET()`:

```
SELECT name 
FROM table_2 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(
        id, 
        (SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', val_1, val_2, val_3) FROM table_1 WHERE id = 1)
      );
```

Or, join the tables:

```
SELECT t2.name 
FROM table_2 t2 INNER JOIN table_1 t1
ON t2.id IN (t1.val_1, t1.val_2, t1.val_3)
WHERE t1.id = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=11a65feb991f0f22d17efa021438c61c).

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly complex JOIN operation.

```sql
SELECT t1.name, 
       t1.val_1, v1.name AS name1,
       t1.val_2, v2.name AS name2,
       t1.val_3, v3.name AS name3
  FROM table_1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table_2 v1 ON t1.val_1 = v1.id
  LEFT JOIN table_2 v2 ON t1.val_2 = v2.id
  LEFT JOIN table_2 v3 ON t1.val_3 = v3.id
```

And adding to @forpas [demo...](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c38b066de7beeb616e52640acaa17285)

But think how much easier your life would be if your table_1 had this normalized layout, with one item per row rather than three.

```
id  name    val 
1   item1   101 
2   item1   102
3   item1   103
4   item2   104 
5   item2   105
6   item2   106
```

Then your query would be

```sql
SELECT t1.name, t1.val, t2.name AS subname
  FROM table_1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.val = t2.id
 WHERE t2.id IN (101, 102, 103) 
 ORDER BY t1.name, t2.name
```

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ddec647b92ffeeac6f524a5ecd70b7f1).